# How to reuse same network twice within a new network in CAFFE

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a pretrained network (let's call it `N`) I would like to use twice within a new network. Anybody knows how to duplicate it? Then I would like to assign a different learning rate to each copy.

For example (`N1` is the 1st copy of `N`, `N2` is the 2nd copy of `N`), the new network might look like:

```
N1 --> [joint ip 
N2 -->    layer]
```

I know how to reuse `N` with a single copy, however, since `N1` and `N2` will have different (finetune) learning rates, I don't know how can I make 2 copies of `N` and assign different learning rate for each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same net twice is something called ["Siamese network"](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html). The way it is implemented in caffe is by explicitly duplicating the network, but using `"name"` param for each parameters blob to create a *single* copy of the underlying parameters. See [this prototxt for example](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/siamese/mnist_siamese_train_test.prototxt).
Once you explicitly defeine the net twice, you can assign different `"lr_mult"` params for each copy.

So suppose your reference network `N` has an input layer (which I'll skip in this example) and an inner product layer named `"ip1"`. Then

```
 layer {
   name: "ip1_a"
   bottom: "data_a"
   top: "ip1_a"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 10
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_w"  # NOTE THIS NAME!
     lr_mult: 1
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_b"
     lr_mult: 2
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "ip1_b"
   bottom: "data_b"
   top: "ip1_b"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 10
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_w"  # NOTE THIS NAME: it's the same!
     lr_mult: 10 # different LR for this branch
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_b"
     lr_mult: 20
   }
 }
 # one layer to combine them     
 layer {
   type: "Concat"
   bottom: "ip1_a"
   bottom: "ip1_b"
   top: "ip1_combine"
   name: "concat"
 }
 layer {
   name: "joint_ip"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "ip1_combine"
   top: "joint_ip"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 30
   }
 }
```

If you finetune, you might need to do some net-surgery in order of the original wieghts to be saved in the `.caffemodel` file with the names `"ip1_w"` and `"ip1_b"`.

Comment: Thank you Shai, Toda! I do need to do some net-surgery, thank you for pointing out the keyword. Here is a link with an example for future reference http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb

Comment: Hi Shai, I get some unexpected behavior when I apply this method. Any chance that the weights are shared between N1 and N2? If yes, is there a way to disable it? I would like N1 and N2 to be independent copies of N. Thanks!

Comment: @user2476373 in that case, you might not need to give names to the parameters blobs, just use the same "name" for the entire layer.

Comment: That doesn't work. When I give two layers the same name, the loaded values are not being loaded to both (not sure whether to either any of them, or just to the 2nd).
Anyway, I solved the issue, by training a single step (with 0 learning rate) of a siamese network, giving each duplicate layer a different name, but let them share the weights.
Then saving a snapshot of this new duplicate network, and init the weights of my network from this snapshot. Thank you again for your assistance here :)

Comment: @user2476373 nice workaround. you could do all these weights manipulations in python

Comment: This example shows using different `lr_mult` values, but this doesn't work in the latest caffe. Instead it will give an error: "Shared param 'ip1w' has mismatched lr_mult."