# Interpreting Caffe models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to interpret and understand the models that are written in Caffe .proto.

Yesterday I came across a sample `'deploy.prototxt'` by [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33986024/773226),  as quoted below:

```
layer {
   name: "ip1_a"
   bottom: "data_a"
   top: "ip1_a"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 10
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_w"  # NOTE THIS NAME!
     lr_mult: 1
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_b"
     lr_mult: 2
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "ip1_b"
   bottom: "data_b"
   top: "ip1_b"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 10
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_w"  # NOTE THIS NAME: it's the same!
     lr_mult: 10 # different LR for this branch
   }
   param {
     name: "ip1_b"
     lr_mult: 20
   }
 }
 # one layer to combine them     
 layer {
   type: "Concat"
   bottom: "ip1_a"
   bottom: "ip1_b"
   top: "ip1_combine"
   name: "concat"
 }
 layer {
   name: "joint_ip"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "ip1_combine"
   top: "joint_ip"
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 30
   }
 }
```

I understand this model definition as:

```
     data_a         data_b
        |             |
        |             |
     -------       -------   
    | ip1_a |     | ip1_b |
     -------       -------
        |             |
        |             |
      ip1_a         ip1_b
        |             |
        |             |
        V             V
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               |
               |
               V
         ------------- 
        |    concat   |
         ------------- 
               |
               |
         ip1_combine
               |
               |
         ------------- 
        |   joint_ip  |
         ------------- 
               |
               |
            joint_ip
```

blob `ip1_a` is trained by layer `ip1_a`, with weights initialized with `ip1_w`(lr:1) and bias initialized with `ip1_b`(lr:2).
blob `ip1_a` is actually the new learned weights which was initialized with `ip1_w`. The learned bias doesn't have a name.

In some models, we can find some layers have:

```
lr_mult:1
lr_mult:2
```

Where the first instance of `lr_mult` always correspond to weights and the next instance for bias.

Are my above understandings correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two data types: the input (training) data and the net's parameters.
During training the input data is fixed to a known training/validation set and only the net parameters are changed. In contrast, when deploying the net, the data changes to new images while the net parameters are fixed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31847179/1714410) for some in-depth description of the way caffe stores these two types of data.

In the example you showed, there are two input training data paths: `data_a` and `data_b` that might be *different* images each time. The input blobs pass through an InnerProduct layer to become `ip1_a` and `ip1_b` blobs respectively. Then they are concatenated into a single blob `ip1_combined` which in turn is fed into the final InnerProduct layer.

On the other hand, the model have a set of parameters: `ip1_w` and `ip1_b` (the weights and bias) of the first inner product layer. In this particular examples the parameters of the layer were explicitly named to indicate the fact that they are *shared* between `ip1_a` and `ip1_b` layers.

As for the two `lr_mult`: then yes, the first is the LR multiplier of the weights, and the second one is for the bias term.

Comment: Thankyou, Shai!
One more question, learning rate is applied during back propagation. Thus, while backpropagating, ip1_w is updated with lr1 in ip1_a layer, and this UPDATED ip1_w is used by ip1_b layer with its lr to update again?

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu the back propagation in this case provides two updates for the parameters `ip1_w` and `ip1_b` once by the pass through `ip1_a` and once by `ip1_b` because in this special case the internal representation of the layers' parameters is linked to the same parameters. As to why these updates use different LR - you'll have to ask the OP of [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983627/how-to-reuse-same-network-twice-within-a-new-network-in-caffe?lq=1).